# error during applying password policy with ldapmodify

Tags: openldap

I want to apply password policy to one particular user, using an LDIF file.
Here is my `test.ldif` file:

```
dn: cn=purval,ou=Users,dc=xxx,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: pwdPolicySubentry
pwdPolicySubentry: Defaultpolicy
```

The command is:

```
ldapmodify -x -D "cn=admin,dc=xxx,dc=com" -w password -f /tmp/addpolicy.ldif
```

The error display is:

```
modifying entry "cn=purval,ou=Users,dc=xxx,dc=com"
ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21)
additional info: pwdPolicySubentry: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ldapmodify` is telling you that the word `Defaultpolicy` is not a valid value for the element `pwdPolicySubentry`.

To fix this you need to identify what your schema tells you the valid values can be, and use one of those valid values.

Here is an example value:

```
pwdPolicySubentry: cn=Default Password Policy,cn=Password Policies,cn=config
```

Comment: Defaultpolicy is the name of the policy i have created.

Comment: Add that policy's DN as the value for `pwdPolicySubentry`